# Deriving a formula for the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8=n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Let $c_n$ denote the number of integer solutions $\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8\right)$ to
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8=n,
$$
with each $x_i \geq 0$. 
(i) Derive a formula for $c_n$ via a combinatorial argument.

Answer:
Using the stars and bars technique
$$*|*|*|*|* |* |* |*$$

Using 8 bins to distribute n distinct balls the answer would be $c_n$ = $\binom{n-1}{7}$
based on the formula $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$

is this the correct approach?

Comment: That works fine.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: No that is incorrect, since your result is not defined for $n<8$, The answer is simply $\frac{(n+7)!}{7!}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8=n,
$$
with each $x_i \geq 0$, can be put into the usual stars and bars form by considering $y_i = x_i + 1$. Then adding $8$ to both sides we get the equivalent equation
$$
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6+y_7+y_8=n+8
$$
with each $y_i \geq 1$. Hence the number of solutions is
$$
\binom{n+8-1}{8-1}
$$
since there are $n+8$ identical balls to distribute among $8$ distinct bins with no bin empty.

Answer (score -1):

> $$
> x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8=n,
> $$
> with each $x_i \geq 0$.

It is wrong, because your solution only works if all $x_i>0$, for exmaple, let $n=8$, then your answer gives $1$, which means only one solution. But in fact, at least we have $8+0+...+0+0=8,~~~~~ 0+8+...+0+0=8,~~~~~ ...,~~~~~ 0+0+...+0+8=8$